# Scrollview with paging enabled scrolling from left to right - iOS

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, scroll, direction

I have read the apple documentation concerning UIScrollView but cannot reach to a clear idea about setting the scrollview with paging enabled scrolling direction starts from Left to RIGHT to suite ARABIC content ... any ideas please ??

Comment: Could you at least give a hint about what you've tried so far, what doesn't work? Typically your question is quite vague without such information.

Comment: yes you are right ... sorry for that I will update .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by using UISlider by setting the slider to the last page of my scrollview in viewdidload

```
CGPoint pnt = CGPointMake(19 * self.scrollView.frame.size.width , 0) ;
    [self.scrollView setContentOffset:pnt animated:YES];

    CGFloat pageWidth = self.scrollView.frame.size.width;
    NSInteger page = (NSInteger)floor((self.scrollView.contentOffset.x * 2.0f + pageWidth) / (pageWidth * 2.0f));
    [slider setValue:page];
```

Now I can scroll by tap and scroll the appropriate direction for arabic content :)

note : 19 is the number of pages in scrollview which equals to no of images - 1 .

Comment: You shouldn't hardcode the number of pages like this, it's bad practice. Instead of `19 * self.scrollview.frame.size.width`, you should use `self.scrollview.contentSize.width - self.scrollview.frame.size.width` to get the X origin of the last page of content, whatever the number of pages is.

Answer (score 1):

What if you just change the `contentOffset` to display the rightmost page on startup?

Comment: Thanks , I tried to do that but how can I get the CGPoint of x given frame size and number of pages ? I face a casting problem